# Confirm "replace all" in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using "replace all" I have selected 17 changes and they are shown in green on the sidebar.  But how can I "confirm" those changes?   I tried Option-Enter but it just re-does the changes *in the sidebar* and not in the actual files.

Notice below that the changes are *not* applied to the file itself yet. And I do not know how to do so.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a matter of a **broken/non-functioning shortcut in *vscode***.

Here is the shortcut to "replace all":

[image]

It does *NOT* work: does nothing.  but if I *click* on the little icon then this happens:

[image]

And then hitting `Replace` gets the job done